# How to use Jest to test async Redux Action Creators with Axios (async/await) and Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, axios

**TL;DR: how to use Jest to test an asynchronous Redux action creator that fetch data from an API using Axios when the async action creator do not returns a promise but use async/await?**

```
export const getConfig = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch(requestConfig());

    const { data } = await axios.get(endpoints.config);

    dispatch(requestConfigFinished(data.data.items));

    // ...
};
```

---

In order to perform asynchronous dispatch, I use Redux Thunk middleware. For example, I have an action creator called `getConfig` that dispatch an action `requestConfig`, then use Axios to fetch some configurations from an API, an then dispatch another action when the API returns an error or data.

Please note that I prefer async/await to Promise for asynchronous code. In the following code, and for this project, I use TypeScript.

Redux actions (actions.ts):

```
export const getConfig = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch(requestConfig());

    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('api/config');

        if (data.status === 200 && data.data && data.data.items) {
            dispatch(requestConfigFinished(data.data.items));
        } else {
            dispatch(requestConfigFinished(data.error, true));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        const { response } = error;
        dispatch(requestConfigFinished(response.data.error, true));
    }
};

export const requestConfig = (): ConfigActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_CONFIG,
    };
};

export const requestConfigFinished = (payload?: object, error?: boolean): ConfigActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED,
        payload,
        error,
    };
};
```

Then the `getConfig` action creator can be called from a component. For example:

```
function App(props: Props) {
    const { getConfig: dispatchGetConfig } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatchGetConfig();
    }, [dispatchGetConfig]);

    // ...
}

const mapDispatch = {
    getConfig
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatch)(Foo);
```

Everything works with this code.

**Now I would like to use Jest to test the Redux actions.**

Testing synchronous action creators is very simple. I have successfully tested both requestConfig`and`requestConfigFinished`:

```
describe('requestConfig', () => {
    it('dispatches REQUEST_CONFIG before fetching config', () => {
        const expectedAction = {
            type: REQUEST_CONFIG,
        };

        expect(actions.requestConfig()).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
});

describe('requestConfigFinished', () => {
    it('dispatches REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED when fetching config has been done', () => {
        const expectedAction = {
            type: REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED,
            payload: mockData.data.items,
        };

        expect(actions.requestConfigFinished(mockData.data.items)).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
});
```

For async action creators there is a great tutorial on the official documentation of Redux [(see here)](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators). However this example do not use async/await. The `fetchTodos` action creator in the doc returns directly a Promise. I've tried several times (many hours!) to change my code, but the test failed.

N.B.: I've tried with and without `jest-mock-axios` library [(repository here)](https://github.com/knee-cola/jest-mock-axios) to Mock Axios. If I can write a first Jest test to test the action creator without mocking the Axios call I could be a first step...

One of my last attempts:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

const mockData = {
    status: 200,
    data: {
        items: {
            'foo': 'bar'
        },
    },
    error: {
        message: null,
        items: [],
    },
};

afterEach(() => {
    mockAxios.reset();
});

describe('getConfig', () => {
    it('dispatches REQUEST_CONFIG and REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED from mock data', async () => {
        const expectedActions = [
            { type: REQUEST_CONFIG }, 
            { type: REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED, payload: mockData.data.items }
        ];

        const store = mockStore({});

        await actions.getConfig();

        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
});
```

Jest output:

```
FAIL  src/__tests__/actions.ts
  ● getConfig › dispatches REQUEST_CONFIG and REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED from mock data

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "type": "REQUEST_CONFIG",
    -   },
    -   Object {
    -     "payload": Object {
    -       "foo": "bar"
    -     },
    -     "type": "REQUEST_CONFIG_FINISHED",
    -   },
    - ]
    + Array []

      39 |             await actions.getConfig();
      40 | 
    > 41 |             expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
         |                                        ^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

PS: my question if not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966274/testing-async-action-creator-using-axios-in-redux-with-jest) because I use a different mocking library and async/await instead of returning a promise on the async action creator.